# Change highlight text brush key in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change the highlight text brush key for the selected row in my datagrid. I've tried many answers from other questions, but nothing worked for me. 
I set the fore- and background of the rows through a datatrigger to different colors. Now I want to keep the fore- and background color, when a row is selected. When I set the highlight brush key to transparent, the background color is the one I want. But if I set the highlight text brush key to transparent too, the text completely disappears. Is there a possibility to change that? I've tried different ways of triggering, but it didn't worked. How can I change the highlight colors for my different cases (in xaml or preferably in code behind) and not set them all to one specific color?

Example how I set the fore- and background:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyData}" Value="MyValue">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyData}" Value="MyValue">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

How I change the highlight colors:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been while but off the top of my head I believe you want something like this.  You set the property values to a default value then the triggers will change the default when the trigger value is matched.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyData}" Value="MyValue">
             <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
             <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
          </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. I set the fore- and background for all rows. The question is how to set the colors, if the row is selected for the different cases, and not only once by default